# Using TikZ spy in 3D

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d, spy

I am trying to use the `spy` library to magnify part of a 3D TikZ drawing. Consider this minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,spy}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[y={(1cm,-0.5cm)},x={(1cm,0.5cm)}, z={(0cm,1cm)},spy using outlines={rectangle, magnification=4, size=2cm, connect spies}]

\coordinate (O) at (1, -1 -0.5);
\draw[->] (O) -- +(0.5, 0,  0) node [right] {$x$};
\draw[->] (O) -- +(0,  0.5, 0) node [below] {$y$};
\draw[->] (O) -- +(0,  0, 0.5) node [above] {$z$};

\draw [fill=blue!20] (0,0,0) -- (3,0,0) -- (3,2,0) -- (0,2,0) -- cycle;

\begin{scope}[canvas is yx plane at z=0,transform shape,every node/.style={scale=0.2}]
\node [align=center] (Text) at (1,1.5) {Make me\\ big!};
\end{scope}

\spy on (Text) in node at (1,1,3);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This works as expected, but I want the small square box to take on the 3D perspective. Like this:

[image]

The resulting zoomed in picture would therefore look as if it was face on:

[image]

Is this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is the `lens` option that allows you to apply transformations on the small “spy” picture (see para 68.3 in the [Tik*Z*/PGF manual [v 3.0.1a]](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf#page=740)):

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,spy}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[y={(1cm,-0.5cm)},x={(1cm,0.5cm)}, z={(0cm,1cm)},spy using outlines={rectangle, magnification=4, size=2cm, connect spies}]

\coordinate (O) at (1, -1 -0.5);
\draw[->] (O) -- +(0.5, 0,  0) node [right] {$x$};
\draw[->] (O) -- +(0,  0.5, 0) node [below] {$y$};
\draw[->] (O) -- +(0,  0, 0.5) node [above] {$z$};

\draw [fill=blue!20] (0,0,0) -- (3,0,0) -- (3,2,0) -- (0,2,0) -- cycle;

\begin{scope}[canvas is yx plane at z=0,transform shape,every node/.style={scale=0.2}]
\node [align=center] (Text) at (1,1.5) {Make me\\ big!};
\end{scope}

\spy[lens={xslant=-1,yslant=.5,scale=3}] on (Text) in node at (1,1,3);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Very similar to Jasper Habicht's nice answer except that you do not have to adjust the lens transformation by hand. So this works regardless of which vectors you choose for you 3D coordinate system.

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,spy}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[y={(1cm,-0.5cm)},x={(1cm,0.5cm)}, z={(0cm,1cm)},spy using outlines={rectangle, magnification=4, size=2cm, connect spies}]

\coordinate (O) at (1, -1 -0.5);
\draw[->] (O) -- +(0.5, 0,  0) node [right] {$x$};
\draw[->] (O) -- +(0,  0.5, 0) node [below] {$y$};
\draw[->] (O) -- +(0,  0, 0.5) node [above] {$z$};

\draw [fill=blue!20] (0,0,0) -- (3,0,0) -- (3,2,0) -- (0,2,0) -- cycle;

\begin{scope}[canvas is yx plane at z=0,transform shape,every node/.style={scale=0.2}]
\node [align=center] (Text) at (1,1.5) {Make me\\ big!};
\pgfgettransform{\mytrafo} % read off transformation
\xdef\mytrafo{\mytrafo} % globalize macro
\end{scope}

\spy[lens={/utils/exec={\pgfsettransform{\mytrafo} % reinstall and invert trafo
\pgftransforminvert},scale=3}] on (Text) in node at (1,1,3);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]