How can I move TikZ pictures in 3D space?
Based on Using TikZ spy in 3D I tried to experiment with a layout/ to develop a layout which should serve as the foundation of a photo album. I came this far:
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/436150/using-tikz-spy-in-3d

\documentclass[tikz,margin=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,spy}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{perspective}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\batchmode

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[y={(1cm,-0.5cm)},x={(1cm,0.5cm)}, z={(0cm,1cm)},spy using outlines={circle, magnification=4, size=2cm, connect spies}]  %", connect spies" für Verbindungelinien

\coordinate (O) at (1, -1 -0.5);
\draw[->] (O) -- +(0.5, 0,  0) node [right] {$x$};
\draw[->] (O) -- +(0,  0.5, 0) node [below] {$y$};
\draw[->] (O) -- +(0,  0, 0.5) node [above] {$z$};

\draw [fill=red!20] (0,0,-.5) -- (3,0,-.5) -- (3,2,-.5) -- (0,2,-.5) -- cycle;
\draw [fill=blue!20] (0,0,0) -- (3,0,0) -- (3,2,0) -- (0,2,0) -- cycle;
\draw [fill=orange!20] (0,0,.5) -- (3,0,.5) -- (3,2,.5) -- (0,2,.5) -- cycle;
\draw [fill=green!20] (0,0,1) -- (3,0,1) -- (3,2,1) -- (0,2,1) -- cycle;

\begin{scope}[canvas is yx plane at z=0,transform shape,every node/.style={scale=0.25}]
\node[rotate=-23, inner sep=0pt] (russell) at (5,5,5) {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}};
\node[rotate=-10, inner sep=0pt] (russell) at (3,3) {\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-b}};
\node[rotate=-20, inner sep=0pt] (russell) at (2,3.5) {\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-b}};
\node[rotate=-10, inner sep=0pt] (russell) at (2,4) {\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck}};
\node[rotate=10, inner sep=0pt] (russell) at (1,5) {\includegraphics[width=2.3cm]{example-image-a}};
\node[rotate=-20, inner sep=0pt] (russell) at (1,3.5) {\includegraphics[width=2.3cm]{example-image-b}};
\node[rotate=-10, inner sep=0pt] (russell) at (1,4) {\includegraphics[width=2.3cm]{example-image-duck}};
\node[rotate=10, inner sep=0pt] (russell) at (4,5) {\includegraphics[width=4.5cm]{example-image-a}};
\node[rotate=-20, inner sep=0pt] (russell) at (4,3.5) {\includegraphics[width=4.5cm]{example-image-b}};
\node[rotate=5, inner sep=0pt] (russell) at (4,4) {\includegraphics[width=4.5cm]{example-image-duck}};
\node[rotate=10, inner sep=0pt] (russell) at (2,5) {\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-b}};
\node[rotate=10, inner sep=0pt] (russell) at (3,5) {\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-c}};
\node[rotate=83, inner sep=0pt] (russell) at (5,3,1) {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}};
\node[inner sep=0pt] (russell) at (3,4) {\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-duck}};
\node[rotate=23, inner sep=0pt] (russell) at (5,4) {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-duck}};
\node[inner sep=0pt] (russell) at (-0,2.7) {\includegraphics[width=7cm]{example-image-c}};
\node [align=center] (Text1) at (.1,2.5) {Make me\\ big 1!};
\pgfgettransform{\mytrafo} % read off transformation
\xdef\mytrafo{\mytrafo} % globalize macro
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[canvas is yx plane at z=0,transform shape,every node/.style={scale=0.2}]
\node [align=center] (Text2) at (.4,1.5) {Make me\\ big 2!};
\pgfgettransform{\mytrafo} % read off transformation
\xdef\mytrafo{\mytrafo} % globalize macro
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[canvas is yx plane at z=0,transform shape,every node/.style={scale=0.2}]
\node [align=center] (Text3) at (5,4) {Make me\\ big 3!};
\pgfgettransform{\mytrafo} % read off transformation
\xdef\mytrafo{\mytrafo} % globalize macro
\end{scope}

% Vergrößerungen
\spy[lens={/utils/exec={\pgfsettransform{\mytrafo} % reinstall and invert trafo
\pgftransforminvert},scale=3}] on (Text2) in node at (0,1,4);
\spy[lens={/utils/exec={\pgfsettransform{\mytrafo} % reinstall and invert trafo
\pgftransforminvert},scale=3}] on (Text1) in node at (4,2,3);
\spy[lens={/utils/exec={\pgfsettransform{\mytrafo} % reinstall and invert trafo
\pgftransforminvert},scale=6}] on (Text3) in node at (6,5,1);

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document} 

Now my questions to the community are:
On the left-hand side of the page I was able to insert a "3D looking stack" and on the right-hand side I was able to develop the foundation of a "chaotic looking" picture collection. Here I would like to be able to "elevate" /to move the pictures along the z-axis but without success. How can I achieve the movement of the pictures along the z-axis so it looks like on the left-hand side of the page? Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Change 0 in canvas is yx plane at z=0 to whatever values you want.

@hpekristiansen Thank you very much for answer! Now I have the possibility to move ALL flying card along the z-axis. How can I just move some of them? Thank you! Edit: I found out that if I double the code between \begin{scope} and \end{scope} I am able to insert a new "layer".

You could also separate them into groups using \begin{scope}[canvas is yx plane at z=...] ... \end{scope}

\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(1cm,0.5cm)}, y={(1cm,-0.5cm)}, z={(0cm,1cm)}]
\begin{scope}[transform shape, every node/.style={scale=0.25}, inner sep=0pt]
\node[canvas is yx plane at z=0, rotate=-23] at (5,5) {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}};
\node[canvas is yx plane at z=1, rotate=-10] at (3,3) {\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-b}};
\node[canvas is yx plane at z=2, rotate=-20] at (2,3.5) {\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-b}};
\node[canvas is yx plane at z=3, rotate=-10] at (2,4) {\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck}};
\node[canvas is yx plane at z=0, rotate=10] at (1,5) {\includegraphics[width=2.3cm]{example-image-a}};
\node[canvas is yx plane at z=1, rotate=-20] at (1,3.5) {\includegraphics[width=2.3cm]{example-image-b}};
\node[canvas is yx plane at z=2, rotate=-10] at (1,4) {\includegraphics[width=2.3cm]{example-image-duck}};
\node[canvas is yx plane at z=3, rotate=10] at (4,5) {\includegraphics[width=4.5cm]{example-image-a}};
\node[canvas is yx plane at z=0, rotate=-20] at (4,3.5) {\includegraphics[width=4.5cm]{example-image-b}};
\node[canvas is yx plane at z=1, rotate=5] at (4,4) {\includegraphics[width=4.5cm]{example-image-duck}};
\node[canvas is yx plane at z=2, rotate=10] at (2,5) {\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-b}};
\node[canvas is yx plane at z=3, rotate=10] at (3,5) {\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-c}};
\node[canvas is yx plane at z=0, rotate=83] at (5,3) {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}};
\node[canvas is yx plane at z=1, rotate=0] at (3,4) {\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-duck}};
\node[canvas is yx plane at z=2, rotate=23] at (5,4) {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-duck}};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Looking so much better than my attempt, Thank you!
